# IIS returns error code 403 in response header and no error page

Tags: iis, ssl, sharepoint

My setup:

- Windows Server 2012
- IIS 8.5
- SharePoint 2013

The SharePoint site is configured to requeire client certificate. If the user has no valid certificate or the password was wrong IIS returns error code 403 in response header. I would like IIS to return a custom error page instead where I could guide the user how to fix the issue.

There are just to many options where I can configure error pages. Which is the right one?

- In IIS I have three possible sites to configure.

  - Default Web Site
  - My web application
  - My web aplication port 443
- Custom errors in web.config
- Error Pages in IIS
- .Net Error Pages in IIS

I have tried some of these options but with no success. Can anybody help me?

Comment: some browsers (especially Internet Explorer) need the error page to be of a certain size. If it is below the browser will show its own message and not yours. Try to provide a page with a minimum of 1KB. Open F12 in your browser and go to network trace, there you will see what gets transferred to the browser.

Comment: At the moment I have not done any special configuration as to error pages. I assume that the error pages listed under IIS>Error Pages in IIS Manager is used. This configuration is the same for all the sites mentioned above. The files are located under C:\inetpub\custerr and are default from installation and are 2 KB each.
In Chrome I just get an error Code 403 in the response header. Probably the same in IE.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit the web.config file in your Visual Studio solution, modify the customErrors section and then check the file into Github to trigger a new deployment.

If you don't use VS, then find your web.config file. Worst case scenario you can edit it directly.

Comment: This application is not deployed on Azure. And also, I've already tried setting custom errors with no  success.